# scanNetworks in ESP32 WiFi.h take too much time. Can we reduce it?

Tags: esp32

I am trying to collect the RSSI data from WiFi access points in ESP32 to tracking target. I have 3 anchor is 3 SSID. The function scan Networks i takes at least 5 seconds and that is a lot for my project. Maybe this because this function scan all SSID near my ESP32 but i just need scan 3 SSID of 3 anchor i have. This is my code for this:

```
int n = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      // Print SSID and RSSI for each network found
      if(WiFi.SSID(i) == "TRUNG DUONG1" ){
       myData.a = WiFi.RSSI(i);}
      if(WiFi.SSID(i) == "TRUNG DUONG2" ){
       myData.b = WiFi.RSSI(i);}     
      if(WiFi.SSID(i) == "TRUNG DUONG3" ){
       myData.c = WiFi.RSSI(i);}}
```

Can you please help me to do it.

Comment: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/esp8266wifi/scan-class.html#scannetworksasync

Comment: i try this code for ESP32 but seem not work
exit status 1
'class WiFiClass' has no member named 'scanNetworksAsync'; did you mean 'scanNetworks'?